# Adb not found in ANDROID_HOME Windows 7 x64

Tags: android, python, windows, sdk, adb

I've just started to learn `SDK UIAutomator tool, but instantly got stuck.
When I run simple code on`Python`:

```
from uiautomator import device as d

d.info
```

I get following traceback:

```
"Adb not found in $ANDROID_HOME path: %s." % os.environ["ANDROID_HOME"])
OSError: Adb not found in $ANDROID_HOME path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
```

I've added both `/tools` and `/platform-tools` to system variables- problem occurred, then I created User variable `ANDROID_HOME` and put `C:\Program Files...\platform-tools` to value, so if to call `echo %ANDROID_HOME%` from `cmd`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` returns, but Python still search for `adb` in `/tools` folder, not in `/platform-tools`. From command line `adb` works perfect. How to make `Python` find the correct way to `adb`?

Resolved as follow:

```
import os
os.environ.__delitem__('ANDROID_HOME')
os.environ.__setitem__('ANDROID_HOME','C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/')
os.environ.update()
```

Comment: Add this `C:\Program Files (x86)\YOUR_ADT_FOLDER\sdk\platform-tools\ `to your system variable path

Comment: Or you can also open your cmd and type `set ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\YOUR_ADT_FOLDER\sdk\platform-tools\`

Comment: so?... the error still?

Comment: Yes. Python still search for adb in Tools folder...

Comment: Then add to the tools folder /sdk/tools

Comment: android-sdk/tools/ folder exists, but adb.exe file actually is in /platform-tools folder/
You mean to add platform-tools files to tools folder?

Comment: Is this script still working nowadays ??
Because I can't make it run

Answer (score 2):

```
set ANDROID_HOME=c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

Or any other place where you put Android SDK in your installation.

Replace 'Administrator' with your local Windows username (based on locale)